# Do recent C++ compilers detect repeated mathematical operations automatically?

Tags: c++, optimization

Let's say I have the following Code:

```cpp
const int n = fun1();
const double x = fun2();
for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    double y = fun3(i) / std::sqrt(x);
    double z = fun4(i) / std::sqrt(x);
    // Do something with the values, e.g., assign them to an array outside the loop
}
```

Do recent compilers manage to optimize it into

```cpp
const int n = fun1();
const double x = fun2();
const double sqrtx = std::sqrt(x); // only computed once instead of possibly 2*n times
for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    double y = fun3(i) / sqrtx;
    double z = fun4(i) / sqrtx;
    // Do something with the values, e.g., assign them to an array outside the loop
}
```

or is it still worth to do such optimizations by hand?

Comment: *Do recent compilers manage to optimize it into* Probably not.  The only way to know is to compile and check the assembly.

Comment: The question is if the compiler knows that `sqrt(x)` always returns the same value for a constant `x`. Maybe!

Comment: Unless the compiler can tell that calling `std::sqrt(x)` produces no side-effects, it cannot tell that that is a valid optimization (because if it *does* have side-effects, it *isn't* valid).

Comment: Compilers are usually very good at detecting invariants so probably yes. Also see : [what has my compiler done for me lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: For "repeated mathematical operations", are you including basic operations such as addition and subtraction?  If so, a compiler can detect classic formulas that are based on integers, like this: `int val = 0; for (int x = 1; x < 20; ++x) val += x;` -- Good, modern compilers will simply set `val` to 190 and remove the loop.

Comment: @ScottHunter well that would be specified by [`res.on.data.races`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/res.on.data.races)

Comment: @Caleth: I didn't take the question to be restricted to functions in `std`.

Comment: Indeed `std::sqrt` is only chosen an example and there are also many libraries bringing their own `sqrt` implementation. But I would think that most well-designed libraries implement it without side effects and try to apply the appropriate modifiers to help compilers.

Comment: you need to try and see. In your example code the compiler very likely does realize that neither `y` nor `z` are used and optimizes away any call to `std::sqrt` completely

Comment: @allo The main issue is where the definition of the function is located.  If it is reachable from the current TU, then you have a shot of getting it optimized sine the compiler can inspect the function for side effects.  If the definition is in another TU then the compiler has a lot less options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(as of the time of writing) clang and gcc don't make this optimisation but MSVC does: https://godbolt.org/z/eKcva1heT. Clang and GCC both call `sqrt` twice, it's too complex for them to determine whether `std::sqrt` has side effects so they can't optimise away the calls.

With libc++ clang implements `std::sqrt` with a single `sqrtsd` instruction but still uses that instruction twice: https://godbolt.org/z/G5sEPYqEP.

If it was an inline function then the compiler potentially can remove duplicate operations. If we change your example to:

```
inline double square(double value)
{
    return value * value;
}

int main()
{
    const int n = fun1();
    const double x = fun2();
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        double y = fun3(i) / square(x);
        double z = fun4(i) / square(x);
        std::cout << x << y;
    }    
}
```

Then all three compilers only do the square once: https://godbolt.org/z/Ys6xPcsc1

Comment: Compile the godbolt sample for msvc with /O2 to see it hoist the sqrt() call.

Comment: @HansPassant doh, always check the compiler output for warnings

Answer (score 1):

Alan's answer is very good. I'm only here to supplement it:

Yes you should always "do such optimizations by hand", even if you have a "sufficiently smart compiler". The reason is that it makes your intentions more obvious.

Also, you should hoist the division too. Multiplications are less strenuous:

```
const int n = fun1();
const double x = fun2();
const double inv_sqrtx = 1 / std::sqrt(x); // only computed once instead of possibly 2*n times
for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    double y = fun3(i) * inv_sqrtx;
    double z = fun4(i) * inv_sqrtx;
    // Do something with the values, e.g., assign them to an array outside the loop
}
```

If you are really dumping `y`and `z` sequentially into arrays, it might even be profitable to use whatever SIMD intrinsics your CPU allows for.